# JDBC Producer in streamsets that could not write data into MySql

Tags: streamsets

I had configured the JDBC connection configuration in the pipeline.

and when the application executes i get the following error on the logs.

```
"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'databaseName.aim_table' doesn't exist"
```

The databaseName is not what I have set.

I have tried many times. it shows the same message that could not find the table in different database, and the question is all the db occurred in the sdc.log are that I had never configured ,and the correct database is never used ,so I want to know how could it find the wrong db and I had checked before start the pipeline and it shows successful:

[image]

Comment: Wow this question is very unclear and hard to read since there is no punctuation anywhere, and everything is in the same long run on sentence with no apparent final statement, and then it shows only an image of something that could be written in text, so ....  See how difficult it is to read?  Put punctuation, paragraphs, put the image inline, show your code, ...  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Nic3500, it was worse than what you read before i edited it. :-) sorry. that's all i could salvage out of it.

Comment: It's already much better :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have anything set in the **Schema Name** configuration for JDBC
>   Producer? This should be blank for MySQL, since you're setting the
>   database/schema name in the connect URL.
>
> Check that your MySQL driver matches the server. In particular, using
>   the current version 8.0.x JDBC driver with a 5.x.x server seems to
>   result in this problem. Download the older 5.1.x driver (currently
>   5.1.46) and it should work.

refer [this](https://ask.streamsets.com/question/2128/jdbc-producer-not-connecting-to-desired-mysql-database/)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is indeed caused by the wrong version of the driver package. I found the correct driver package and successfully wrote the data to the target table. add aonther point, I have set the SCHEMA NAME to blank and defined the database name in the connect URL for mysql.
My English is not good. Please forgive me.